# How to cast from one typedef type to another?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, shared-ptr, typedef

I am using c++ in VS2017

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<my::myclass::Writer<mytype::myvar>> mySharedTypePtr;

mySharedTypePtr mySharedtestPtr;

typedef int32_t my_int32_type;
```

I need to compile this code

```
my_int32_type my_32_method(my_int32_type x, float y){//do something};

my_int32_type mt_32test;
```

attempt 1

```
mt_32test = my_32_method((my_int32_type )mySharedtestPtr, float y);// did not work error--> 'type cast': cannot convert from 'mySharedTypePtr' to 'my_int32_type '
```

attempt 2

```
mt_32test = my_32_method(static_cast<my_int32_type>mySharedtestPtr, float y);// did not work error--> 'type cast': cannot convert from 'mySharedTypePtr' to 'my_int32_type '
```

I am trying to convert from one typedef to another **mySharedtestPtr** to **my_int32_type**

how to do this?

Comment: `mySharedtestPtr` and `my_int32_type`, unrelated types, what you trying to do impossible.

Comment: The compiler is correct – you can't convert between them. There is probably some `int32` that you can access through a `my::myclass::Writer<mytype::myvar>` which you are supposed to pass. (Related: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is a complex class, there's more in than just a simple pointer. If you are interested in the stored objects address, then you could do: `static_cast<int32_t>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(thePointer.get()))`. The via point of `uintptr_t` is necessary to catch up with correct sizes of the involved data types. I'm not sure why you would want to do so, though, you are pretty likely losing information that way and won't be able to reconstruct the pointer anyway.

Comment: @Aconcagua your method looks work for me, if get it into the new my_int32_type variable there is no issue with the original shared ptr right?

Comment: @kingmihi `get` leaves the `shared_ptr` object intact, it returns a *copy* of the internally stored pointer value (all pointers are passed around that way, just being copies of the respective memory addresses). If you now (indirectly) cast to a int32_t that's just another (partial!) copy. Pointers on typical modern desktop hardware have 8 bytes of size, though, so the four most significant bytes get lost. Reconstructing the pointer value from the integer won't be possible then.

Comment: And be aware that two distinct `std::shared_ptr` instances holding the same object are not distinguishable. If that's what you need, you might try by taking the address of the object. Be aware then, too, that these addresses can easily get invalid if you take them of objects with local scope. What do you actually want to achieve? Producing an int32_t from a shared pointer might not be suitable for!

Comment: @Aconcagua can you check my new question it is related to this but no sharedpointer involves in it....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67468168/how-to-pass-c-namesapced-scoped-object-to-another-typed-c-method

Comment: @kingmihi So if that's what you are trying to do then out of luck, won't work and never will, see explanation there.