# How to pass C++ namesapced scoped object to another typed C method?

Tags: c++, eclipse, type-conversion, data-distribution-service

I am trying to use c-CycloneDDS [this waitset code](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/blob/c66d34b4ac23681ecabc3e374bd3fb8febaccf9b/examples/throughput/publisher.c#L188) in c++ CycloneDDS application, CycloneDDS does not have separate c++ implementation for waitset methods (VS2017)

```
waitset = dds_create_waitset(participant);// c example, here participant is a dds_entity_t type
```

The return type of this dds_entity_t which is an int32_t

But in C++ CycloneDDS we create participant as follows

```
dds::domain::DomainParticipant participant_Cpp;
```

How to use participant_Cpp in c++ application code? like this

```
waitset = dds_create_waitset(participant_Cpp);// this does not work due to types are not matching

error 'dds_entity_t dds_create_waitset(dds_entity_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'dds::domain::DomainParticipant' to 'dds_entity_t'
```

Comment: Looks like you should use the C++ wrapper `WaitSet`, they have some [examples](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds-cxx/blob/master/src/ddscxx/include/dds/core/cond/TWaitSet.hpp)

Comment: Without having seen the documentation pretty sure there's some function like `dds_create_participant` returning a `dds_entity_t` which is intended to be passed to e. g. `dds_create_waitset`.  This `dds_entity_t` integer might be an index into some internal array or whatever else. Pretty sure though it is not compatible to the address of some C++ type. The only way this might work would be the C library being internally implemented in C++ and dds_entity being mapped to void*, uintptr_t or similar, but that's incompatible to int32_t (on most modern platforms at least).

Comment: The "proper" way to do it in C++ is indeed using `WaitSet`.

You can also get the `dds_entity_t` that the C API uses with `participant_Cpp->get_ddsc_entity()` (that works for any entity in the C++ API).